# Como optimizar EntityFramework 6

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Alguien me puede ayudar a cómo optimizar `Entity Framework`, por la cual se tarda varios segundo al momento de cargar el `EDMX` (Conceptual model, Store Model, Mapping Model).

Comment: Tienes que detallar más la pregunta. Así como esta no hay forma de ayudarte sin adivinar el problema, y la pregunta será cerrada rápidamente

Comment: No veo porque cerrar la pregunta, es simple la pregunta, y por supuesto no necesita código, la pregunta es de optimización  en e EF y no necesita detallarse, simplemente quiere saber como hacer para levantar el contexto mas rapido. No me parece que tengan que cerrar esta pregunta!.

Comment: Creo que la pregunta se refiere a reducir el tiempo que le cuesta a Entity Framework procesar el modelo y preparar el mapeo con la base de datos y me parece un tema interesante. En [este artículo de la MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469601.aspx) se pueden ver mas detalles. ¿Quizás fuera interesante reabriría y reformularla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo te recomiendo que utilices una estrategia de inicialización, esto ayuda a que la base de datos sea inicializada una sola vez y no tenga que volver a cargar el contexto cada vez haces alguna operación CRUD

Toma como referencia esta [url](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Creo que la pregunta se refiere a reducir el tiempo que le cuesta a Entity Framework procesar el modelo y preparar el mapeo con la base de datos. Ese proceso se puede optimizar pre-generando las vistas de mapeo como explican en [este artículo de la MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469601.aspx)